# Script or executable to set homepage for default browser, and auto-load browser on PC startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, automation, gpo

We're launching our new company intranet soon and to ensure that everyone uses it (or at least see's it), we'd like to create an automated procedure for changing the default browser's (IE11, FF, Chrome) homepage to the new URL for the intranet.  We'd also like to make the browser load on computer startup.

Is there a way to do this via a batch or VB script, executable or GPO?

I had a feeling that GPO's would be the easiest way to enforce the home/start page change.
One small problem though - not all of our offices are running Server 2012 or above and some aren't even running a DC.  Those few only have 3-4 staff and are just running standalone desktops.

So I was hoping to create a compressed package for them to download with a few shortcuts (.lnk), registry fixes, VB scripts and the like all to run from a single batch file.

I have the shortcut, the icon, a registry tweak for IE, a batch script for FF and I was going to create a batch file to automate the procedure.  But I'm missing a start page modifier for Chrome.
And maybe there's a better way to do all of it...  because the batch file will need to be run with administrative privileges.
I'd like to make it as seamless and easy as possible for those staff that are not very computer literate.

[image]

Also - one of our offices uses Macs... Is there a Mac equivalent to this?  They mostly use Safari or Chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763171/batch-file-to-set-homepage-in-all-browsers

Comment: I've already read that question.  That's where I got my reg tweak and FF script from.
There's no answer for Chrome there though and nothing for doing it on Macs as well as Windows.

Comment: Chrome *is* mentioned there -- see [@Sunny's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20322361/5047996)...

Comment: yeah - no!  It is mentioned and that's about it.  Unless I'm failing to read between the lines, there is no instruction or process for automating the change of Chrome's home/start page.  I've re-read the answers and comments and cannot determine how they automate the process.  And moreover - what's the point of adding "javascript:(function(){ window.location.href='http://www.google.com/';})();" to the home page pref field (which doesn't exist on modern chrome) when you can just add the direct URL...?

Comment: I've managed to find that I can force chrome (or any browser) by modifying the "Target" of a shortcut's properties and adding the desired URL after the closing ".  eg. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://companyintranet.website.com.
But how can I automate this process?  Surely it can be done because I've come across malware that does it.